# Importing * in Python 3.7 Using __init__.py File

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-module, python-3.7

First of all here is my directory structure:

```
Root
   - models 
        car.py 
        __init__.py 
   hello.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` I have the following:

```
__all__ = ["car"]
```

Inside `hello.py` I try to import everything from models folder:

```
from models import *

car = Car()
```

This gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 4, in <module>
    car = Car()
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW I would generally recommend to avoid ever importing `*`. It's never necessary, and ["explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). This is the advice that [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports) gives as well: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Answer (score 3):

You will have to specify what class you would like to import into the attribute `__all__` of your `__init__.py` file. See below the example:

```
from car import *
__all__ = ["Car"]
```

Comment: Now I get the following: from models import *
AttributeError: module 'models' has no attribute 'Car'

Comment: Where do these lines go? I already have __all__ = ["Car"] inside __init__.py file.

Comment: @johndoe : That is the content of your `__init__.py` file, and don't forget, it is `Car` not `car` like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the class `Car` directly accessible in `hello.py` after you do `from models import *`, in the `__init__.py` file, put `from models.car import Car`.

`__all__`, on the other hand, *typically* lists names of *modules*, like what you have above. You could change `hello.py` to be as follows and your current `__init__.py` that consists of `__all__ = ["car"]` will work:

```
from models import *
car_obj = car.Car() # Reference module.class instead of just the class
```

Answer (score 0):

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

This means that your `hello.py` has just imported the `car` module into it's namespace, *not* the `Car` class. Therefore this would work.

```
from models import *
auto = car.Car()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one step there.

Try:

```
from models import *

car = car.Car()
```

Or try:

```
from models.car import *

car = Car()
```

Answer (score 0):

`__all__` just controls what will be exported by using `*` in current scope.

In your case, `Car` is not in your `__init__.py`'s scope. So it is meaningless.

To solve this problem, you need to import `Car` into `__init__.py`'s scope, that's all.

I understand that you think just by using `__all__`, you can directly access the class in `car.py`, but that's not true. `__all__` does nothing else but **control exports in current scope**.